# Limit concurrent logins by an authenciated user in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I have been looking and playing with Firebase and I found it really interesting.

So far I have tried some simple authentication and security policy setting but now I have a problem which does not seem to be covered in the documentation and I couldn't find anything on Google or here.

The problem is that I cannot find a way to limit the number of concurrent logins per email/password.

I would like to have an option where paid customers can only login from 1 IP at a time. In other words I don't want people to be able to purchase an account and then share the same  with friends and family and then all connect to the system at the same time using the same credentials.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You will control access by writing to a path in Firebase whenever a user logs in. Then you can check that path to ensure only one user exists at a time:

- write a value to a path each time a user logs in (e.g. `logged_in_users/$user_id`)
- use [onDisconnect()](https://www.firebase.com/docs/javascript/ondisconnect/index.html) to delete that value when user disconnects
- check that path for a value on an additional login attempt
- show an error if the value exists or allow login if not

This takes care of the UX portion. To secure it against exploits, you will take advantage of Firebase's comprehensive [security rules](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security-quickstart.html):

- generate your own authentication tokens using the [custom login strategy](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/custom-login.html)
- include the IP address as part of the data inside the token
- reject login attempts if the logged_in_users/$user_id is set to a different IP address
- write security rules to prevent read/write from other IPs

Assuming you've generated tokens containing an IP address, your security rules could look something like the following:

```
".read": "root.child('logged_in_users/'+auth.uid).val() === auth.ip_address"
```

Comment: Thank you for the respond. For the first part of your answer the document says "Note that disconnect operations are only fired once. If a client disconnects and then reconnects again, the disconnect operations will need to be initiated again." Also what happens if the user just closes the browser tab or lose the Internet connection (mobile networks etc) wouldn't then the user appear online indefinitely?

Comment: Regarding the second part of the solution, I am confused is auth.ip_address and undocummented feature cause i dont see anything here https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/rule-expressions/auth.html or that is simply a value we provide through custom login for both id and ip_address? In the case of we providing both then the condition will always be true.

Comment: onDisconnect is managed by the server, so any time the client loses connection, it is fired, regardless of how the client becomes disconnected. When the client reconnects, you would need to reestablish the onDisconnect (that would ideally be part of writing the `logged_in_users` record). Auth.ip_address represents something you would add to a custom token you build yourself, see the [custom login docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/custom-login.html) referenced in the bullets. Cheers.

Comment: is custom login we provide the value for both id and ip_address, so if for any login attempt the ".read": "root.child('logged_in_users/'+auth.id).val() === auth.ip_address" would be valid. This security rule is like saying ".read": "true == ture"

Comment: Regarding the onDisconnect. How does a javascript defined on client side gets run on the server side? Unless there is an documented way to define server sides event that also doesn't seem to work for network dropouts or closing tabs.

Comment: At the onDisconnect is called, the operation to be performed is sent to the server. When the client disconnects, the server notices and triggers the action.