# Restrict incoming accounts using one email

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have an application that uses authentication methods from firebase. Is there a way to have one email registered on firebase user authentication can only be used on one device and other devices can not login using the same email and password already in use

Comment: There is nothing built into Firebase to limit users to being signed in from a single device. You can build something on top. I've seen multiple developers struggle with this, so YMMV. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21321234/how-to-prevent-simultaneous-logins-of-the-same-user-with-firebase, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19754819/limit-concurrent-logins-by-an-authenciated-user-in-firebase, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35410391/how-to-handle-multiple-connections-of-the-same-user-on-firebase