# Does firebase auth provides any built in features to avoid concurrent user sessions?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I would like to prevent simultaneous user login for the same user from another with firebase authentication in an android application. I want to prevent the user from logging in to an android device when there is an active session for the same user exists in another device. I am fine even with force logging out of the existing session when a new request comes from a second device.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limit concurrent logins by an authenciated user in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19754819/limit-concurrent-logins-by-an-authenciated-user-in-firebase)

Comment: This looks like a workaround. I am looking for a built-in support