# Firebase and react single user login

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am implementing a web application that uses firebase and react authentication, I want to restrict login to only one session per user, in such a way that if the same user tries to login to their account on two devices at the same time, just let it login the first, and in the second I get an error message, but I am not clear about what I should do to achieve this, I would greatly appreciate the help provided.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limit concurrent logins by an authenciated user in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19754819/limit-concurrent-logins-by-an-authenciated-user-in-firebase)

Answer (score 0):

If you have `users` collection where you keep extra information about your users, you could add an extra field there `loggedIn` and set it to `true` when the user logs in.

If you don't have this collection, create one specifically for this purpose. Call it something like `loggedInUsers` and keep `uid` of logged in users there.

Then after each login, check either `loggedIn` value on the `user` or check if `uid` is present in `loggedInUsers`, and allow/decline as needed.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your answer, first I thought about this same solution but in case the user refreshes the page where he is currently being the persistent validation, the access to the user who was already there would be blocked.